# la propiedad closest me da error

Tags: javascript

si hago un console me trae bien el objeto
solo funciona cuando no hay onclick pero cuando coloco onclick se me hecha a perder. al boton lo encierran
**una etiqueta td y un tr de class="tr"**

Hola aparte de la solucion closest que otra manera puede haber ?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'closest')

```
printf(
  '<td class="cantidad_disponible" id="Q_' .
  $e->id_productos .'">'. 
  $e->cantidad_disponible.'</td>'
);
```

```
function addToCarritoItem(id, e){
  let numero=id.target
  const item = numero.closest('.tr');

  const id_prod = item.querySelector('.id_n').textContent;
```

Comment: Por favor lee [ask].

Comment: ¿Será que en vez de `let numero=id.target` debería ser `let numero=e.target`?

Comment: fijate si te sirve https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/272343/81450